# How to get a Aggregate - $group counting results on $addFields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query.

```
   db.Collection.aggregate([
  {
        "$match":{
            "index": 1
                 }
  },

  {
        "$addFields":{
            "DATE": $var1
            "array":"$array1
                     }
  }
```

])

This is the result of the query.

**OUTPUT1**

```
    {
        "DATE" : 181019
        "array" : 100,101,105,106,201,205,208,209
    }
...
...
```

and I'm going to get a $group results.
I will use $array1.

```
    db.Collection.aggregate([
  {

        {
         $group:{
             "_id":"$array1",
             "count":{"$sum" : 1}
                }
        },

        {
        $sort: {"count" : -1}

        }


  }
])
```

**OUTPUT2**

```
{
 "_id" : [
100,
101,
105,
106,
201,
205,
208,
209],

"count" : 4.0

}
```

"count" results will copy on all results.

But $group will make a bad structure to read all data.

How do I merge ALL **OUTPUT1** with $group "count" of **OUTPUT2**?

```
     {
            "$addFields":{
                "DATE": $var1
                "array":"$array1
                "count": $count
                         }
      }
```

Using $group "count", but I don't want $group structure.

```
   {
        "DATE" : 181019
        "array" : 100,101,105,106,201,205,208,209
        "count" : 4.0
    },
    {
        "DATE" : 181019
        "array" : 103,104,105,106,201,205,208,210
        "count" : 12.0
     }
...
...
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: So I found the answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mongo group query how to keep fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662405/mongo-group-query-how-to-keep-fields)

I found what I want.
The answer is $group trick.

first,  Shifts  $addfield's query  to $group{query}.

Secondly, add {$first:{}} to $addfield's query
That makes $addfield's query $group query.

```
$group:{
_id: $group_var,
name:{$first:{$addfield's query}}
"count": $count
}
```

This is the result of putting it in.

```
 db.Collection.aggregate([
  {

        {
         $group:{
             "_id":"$array1",
             "array":{"$first":"$array1}
             "count":{"$sum" : 1}
                }
        },

        {
        $sort: {"count" : -1}

        }


  }
])
```

Comment: But It can't see all the data. It Just shows $group results.